# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra "nomás"?

Tags: etimología, diferencias-regionales

Siempre me ha parecido curioso el uso de la palabra *nomás* como sinónimo de *solamente*:

> [**nomás**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QZn9Wpr)
>   1. adv. Arg., Bol., Chile, Col., C. Rica, Ec., Hond., Méx., Nic., Par., Perú y Ven. no más (‖ solamente).
>   2. adv. Arg., Chile, Col., Ec., El Salv., Hond., Méx., Par., Perú, Ur. y Ven. U. en oraciones exhortativas, generalmente pospuesto, para añadir énfasis a la expresión. *Pase nomás*. *Atrévase nomás*.
>   3. adv. Arg., Col., El Salv., Méx., Nic. y Ur. Apenas, precisamente.

Por lo que dice la RAE se usa en todos los países de Hispanoamérica (bueno, echo en falta Uruguay en la primera acepción). Para mí, la etimología es clara: *no* + *más*.

En España no se usa y asumí que en Hispanoamérica se estaría usando desde siempre. Para mi sorpresa, el [Mapa de diccionarios](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/mapa-de-diccionarios) me indica que se introdujo en 1992; posteriormente, en 2001 la 2ª y 3ª acepción ampliaron la lista de países en que se usa. El [Nuevo tesoro lexicográfico de la lengua española](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle) abunda en lo mismo e incluye la referencia de 1992.

En todos los casos se ve que empezó por Argentina, Bolivia, México y Venezuela y luego creció hacia el resto.

Teniendo en cuenta que la distribución geográfica de estos países es de lo más variopinta y son muy lejanos entre sí, habiendo otros en medio, ¿a qué responde esta inclusión de la palabra?

Y más importante: ¿cuál es su origen? En catalán existe prácticamente la misma palabra, *només*, pero precisamente esta lengua geográficamente podría haber influenciado el castellano de España. Pero ha pasado lo contrario: se usa en todos los países menos este.

Comment: El [diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=nom%C3%A1s) te detalla un poco las acepciones.

Comment: Por lo que tengo entendido proviene de "nada más", pero lentamente se  convirtió de "namas" a "nomas"

Comment: @fedorqui: siendo puristas, ¿no debería ser Hispanoamérica en vez de Latinoamérica? http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=latinoam%C3%A9rica

Comment: @user13560 tienes toda la razón. Escuché tanto [la canción de Calle 13](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkFJE8ZdeG8) que ahora siempre me viene a la cabeza _Latinoamérica_ en lugar de _Hispanoamérica_, incluso cuando lo correcto es lo segundo. Gracias, lo edito ahora mismo.

Comment: @fernando.reyes curioso, en catalán es simplemente grafía aglutinada de _no més_.

Comment: @fernando.reyes pues tiene sentido, porque "nada más" equivaldría a "simplemente", por lo que el ejemplo de "pase nomás" sería "simplemente pase".

Comment: Un mecanismo de la lengua para ampliarse y renovarse es la aceptación o adopción de expresiones comunes o de uso generalizado, aunque estos sean de origen coloquial. Si un determinado colectivo redujo "no más" a "nomás" y su uso se extendió y perduró en el tiempo, es de esperar que tarde o temprano fuese recogido por el diccionario. Como whisky y güisqui. Esta última se recoge a raíz de transcribir whisky por su fonética. Al final se aceptó en el DRAE

Comment: @Laiv creo que tu comentario es muy acertado. ¿Te animas a convertirlo en respuesta?

Comment: Rayos!. Si se introdujo y cobró popularidad en 1992, no sería raro que fuera gracias a un programa de la televisión mexicana (distribuida a menudo a latam). El comediante Héctor Suarez, tiene un personaje que la utilizaba como cierre para discusiones. Era un programa de sátira social llamado ¿Qué nos pasa?. Lo agrego como comentario por que no estoy seguro que sea una respuesta.

Comment: @celerno pues a mí me da que es una hipótesis con mucho fundamento. Nótese eso sí que [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nom%C3%A1s&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnom%C3%A1s%3B%2Cc0) muestra que su uso ha ido creciendo desde 1960 aproximadamente. ¿Será que por ese tiempo se usó en otro programa?

Comment: @fedorqui aunque tu referencia de la RAE nos incluye a los Colombianos aquí casi no se usa y la investigación de Carlos lo demuestra. La expresión la conocemos a través de las muchísimas telenovelas mexicanas que se ven por aquí. Yo siempre había pensado que era una expresión netamente mexicana

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos a buscar un poco de información en el [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) a ver qué encontramos. Por de pronto, buscando simplemente "nomás" encontramos 501 casos, con los siguientes países como ganadores en el ranking de uso:

```
MÉXICO      41.11%  (206 casos)
ARGENTINA   24.15%  (121 casos)
PARAGUAY    16.36%  (82 casos)
PERÚ        9.78%   (49 casos)
URUGUAY     4.99%   (25 casos)
```

Curiosamente, las primeras apariciones son en México:

> *[...] y otros no comían hasta el mediodía, una vez **nomás**, y en la noche no gustavan cosa alguna [...]*
>
> <sup>Fray Bernardino de Sahagún, "Historia general de las cosas de Nueva España", México (1576-1577).</sup>

Y en España (!), gracias a Lope de Vega:

> *Carlomagno: [...] ¿Por qué parte os parece que la entremos?*
>
> *Durandarte: Yo te la pintaré, señor invicto, por la costa **nomás**, porque tú puedas escoger el lugar que más te agrade.*
>
> <sup>Lope de Vega Carpio, "El casamiento en la muerte", España (c. 1597).</sup>
>
> ---
>
> *Alcira: Que dellos no estoy quejosa.*
>
> *Baudeles: ¿Pues de quién?*
>
> *Alcira: De vos **nomás**, porque fingís sentimiento.*
>
> <sup>Lope de Vega Carpio, "El hijo de Reduán", España (1604).</sup>

Por lo que parece que el origen podría ser una versión reducida de "nada más", o como sinónimo de "simplemente" o "solamente". La siguiente aparición en el CORDE ya es en 1778 en un texto argentino anónimo:

> Apéese **nomás**, válgate Barrabás, dentre pues que cojea de los pies.
>
> <sup>Anónimo, "El amor de la estanciera", Argentina (1778).</sup>

cuyo uso ya se parece bastante más al que se le da hoy día en Hispanoamérica.

Dados los primeros usos, existe una posibilidad de que la expresión se originase en España (en su forma ya unida en una palabra) por la época de los primeros viajes a América (unos cuantos años antes de la primera aparición mencionada en México), y se haya mantenido como expresión latente hasta su relativamente reciente explosión en el uso, sobre todo en Hispanoamérica (34 casos en el siglo XIX, 471 casos en el siglo XX más 1359 en el [CREA](http://corpus.rae.es/creanet.html)). El *top 5* en el CREA es:

```
MÉXICO      52.94%  (719 casos)
PERÚ        16.78%  (228 casos)
ARGENTINA   15.02%  (204 casos)
URUGUAY     3.60%   (49 casos)
BOLIVIA     2.65%   (36 casos)
```

Si nos tenemos que remontar aun más atrás, hay que buscar la expresión en su forma antigua (y separada) *non más*:

> Ca si dixiere que lo oyo a un onbre solo e **non mas** non lo deven creer [...]
>
> <sup>Anónimo, "Siete Partidas de Alfonso X. BNM I 766", España (1491).</sup>

E incluso en el "Cantar de Myo Çid":

> Los VI dias de plazo passados los an: Tres an por troçir, sepades que **non mas**.