# ¿Cómo puedo traducir el modismo inglés "to do something on the hoof"?

Tags: traducción, modismos, solicitud-de-modismo

En inglés se dice "to do something on the hoof".

[Por ejemplo](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-37797134):

> David Cameron income tax law promise 'made up on the hoof'

[Que significa](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/on-the-hoof): Si haces algo, lo haces mientras estás moviéndote o haciendo otra cosa, a menudo sin darle la atención que merece.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Otra posibilidad es la expresión coloquial `A matacaballo`.

> [**matacaballo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OZreKVX)
>
> loc. adv. coloq. Atropelladamente, muy deprisa.

Esta locución no tene el significado de "hecha según se van viendo las cosas" sino "hecha muy deprisa y sin prestarle la debida atención".

Comment: Muy buena, esta no la conocía.

Answer (score 8):

Se me ocurre que una posible opción pueda ser:

> **[a la ligera](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NIVZq3a#2Mjffu7)**
>
> 1. loc. adv. Con prisa y sin reflexión.

No estoy seguro de si se respetan todas las connotaciones del original. "Hacer algo a la ligera" significa que lo has hecho sin prestar la debida atención a los detalles, pero el motivo es generalmente la prisa, y no el estar pendiente de otra cosa (aunque podría ser).

También se me ocurre:

> **[de refilón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VcW7uhP)**
>
> 1. loc. adv. Oblicuamente, de soslayo, al sesgo.
> 2. loc. adv. De paso, de pasada.

"Hacer algo de refilón" es hacerlo aprovechando la ocasión, ligeramente y sin detenerse a pensarlo. Tampoco estoy seguro de que contenga todo el significado original.

A ver si a la tercera atino un poco más:

> **[sobre la marcha](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ON4wO00#2W36k3D)**
>
> 1. loc. adv. Deprisa, inmediatamente, en el acto.
> 2. loc. adv. A medida que se va haciendo algo.

Esta expresión sí recoge el hecho de hacer algo a medida que haces otra cosa. Aunque no incluye el que lo que se hace sobre la marcha pueda estar hecho sin que se le preste la suficiente atención, creo que esa parte va implícita. La pista definitiva me la dio el ejemplo en la web del diccionario de Cambridge:

> *I've got a meeting downtown in 20 minutes so I'll have lunch on the hoof.*
>   Tengo una reunión en el centro en 20 minutos, así que comeré sobre la marcha.

Comment: +1. "Sobre la marcha" habría sido mi primera opción

Comment: @Diego y la mía, si me hubiera acordado antes. :-D El ejemplo de la reunión fue el que me abrió los ojos.

Comment: Los chilenos no diríamos "a la ligera", excepto en situaciones muy formales. Diríamos en cambio "a la rápida" o "a la carrera".

Comment: Yo voto por "a la ligera", para mi "sobre la marcha" es más algo no planeado que hecho sin poner atención +1

Comment: Encontré "_a la buena de dios_". No lo conozco, me imagino que es un dicho español. ¿Es equivalente a los que indicas?

Comment: @Rodrigo es equivalente a "como Dios le dio a entender", significa "sin preparación, al azar". Se usa por ejemplo para decir que estás haciendo algo sin saber realmente lo que haces.

Comment: También aplica "al aventón" en México, y particularmente en la zona del Bajío se acostumbra decir "al chilazo" pero definitivamente las 3 opciones de esta respuesta son más universales que la respuesta del verdugo de corceles. Punto extra: son políticamente correctas! =)

Answer (score 4):

Carlos Alejo menciona distintas opciones que comparto. Añadiría también:

> [**deprisa y corriendo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CGIX0S0)
>
> 1. loc. adv. Con la mayor celeridad, atropelladamente, sin detención o pausa alguna.

La repetición de elementos (tanto *deprisa* como *corriendo*) enfatiza la velocidad con la que algo se hace, siendo esta su única cualidad respecto otras más útiles como la atención a los detalles, el método, etc.

Por ejemplo una madre le puede decir al hijo:

> — No me extraña que el profesor te pusiera mala nota por los ejercicios, los hiciste deprisa y corriendo antes de ir al entrenamiento de fútbol.

Comment: I think the _corriendo_ part captures nicely the idiom of being on the hoof as does _sobre la marcha_ in another answer.

Answer (score 4):

El texto del artículo:

> Mr Gill, who was Mr Cameron's head of strategic communications in charge of the "Grid" outlining Downing Street's planning agenda from 2011 to 2015, told BBC Radio 4's Week in Westminster: "Sometimes when a vacuum is there, it makes the government do some stupid things.
>
> "When I was in government, we made some announcements *on the hoof* just to fill that vacuum."

Es decir, más o menos:

> "A veces, cuando hay un vacío en una plataforma política, eso causa que el gobierno haga algunas tonterías.
>
> "Cuando yo estaba en el gobierno, hicimos algunos anuncios ***improvisados*** nomás para llenar ese vacío."

También se podría decir

> Hicimos algunos anuncios ***sin pensar***, nomás para llenar etc.

Me parece que la mayoría de las definiciones de "on the hoof" en inglés no reflejan el uso que se dio en el artículo citado.  Pero encontré un [recurso](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/on+the+hoof.html) que creo que ayuda:

> If you decide something *on the hoof*, you do it without planning, responding to events as they happen. (usingenglish.com)

No sé cómo documentar "sin pensar," pero

> la *improvisación* consiste en concebir y ejecutar cualquier acción de forma simultánea.  ([wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improvisaci%C3%B3n))

Comment: ¡Interesante uso de [nomás](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18309/1674)! Y sí, parece que más que un modismo, con una sola palabra como _improvisado_ hay más que suficiente.

Comment: Para los que no estén acostumbrados al "nomás", aquí se puede leer como "con tal de" en lugar de "nomás para" o simplemente "solo" en lugar de "nomás"

Comment: @Brian - gracias, no sabía que mi "nomás" no es universal.  Creo que podría poner "simplemente": "Cuando yo estaba en el gobierno, hicimos algunos anuncios improvisados **simplemente** para llenar ese vacío," o "tan solo": "Cuando yo estaba en el gobierno, hicimos algunos anuncios improvisados tan solo para llenar ese vacío." Lástima que no todos van a entender "nomás" -- es una expresión tan útil y directa.

Answer (score 3):

Puede ser precipitadamente:

> [**precipitadamente**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TvqvBaG)
>
> 1. adv. Sin consideración ni prudencia tomé la decisión precipitadamente y ahora me arrepiento.
> 2. Con mucha prisa salí precipitadamente de casa y me dejé las llaves dentro.

En inglés un significado para "On the Hoof" es

> without great thought or preparation

Precipitadamente cabe como anillo al dedo.

Comment: ¡Buena sugerencia! Y bienvenido a [spanish.se] :)

Comment: @fedorqui ¡Gracias! Un gusto estar aqui.